# Frequency of data occurence in Excel Column based on the certain condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

I have a column (Table 1 below) with time data in 24 hour format saved as text.I want Table 2 to be populated by the hour and adding all the occurrences for the hour.

So one occurrence is at 0102. This falls within  an hor range of 12:30am to 01:30pm. I want the count to be 1 for 01:00.
If an occurrence falls between 01:30 to 02:30 I want the count to be 1 for 02:00.
Also if time is 04:55 it should show count for 05:00  as 1. Basically rounding to the closest time and showing a count for that. It should round of to the nearest time and add the number of occurrences also. Thats why 06:00 is 2. to account for 0622 and 0614.

For example:

```
TABLE 1                   TABLE2 (Expected results)
Column A                  Column A     Column B
0102                      01:00        1 
0222                      02:00        2
0223                      03:00        0
0455                      04:00        0
0622                      05:00        1
0614                      06:00        2
```

**NOTE** In ***B1*** we get **1** because value in **A1** of ***TABLE1*** is *0102* and falls between 12:30 and 01:30, thus represented by ***01:00*** in **A1** in ***TABLE 2***. We have two values in *Table1* between 01:30 and 02:30: one is in **A2** and the second is in **A3**, so we expect **2** in **B2** in *TABLE 2*, the time range which is represented by 02:00 in **A2**. We attribute **0** to cells **B3** and **B4** in *Table2* because there isn't any data  in *Table1* between 02:30-03:30 and 03:30-04:30, therefore they get **0** in their corresponding cells in *Table2*. However, we have two instances of data, *0622* and *0612* in *Table1* which fall between 05:30 and 06:30, so value **2** is attributed to **B6**.

How do I do this using a formula?

Please help.

Comment: Could you please clarify the conversion logic as your description is a bit unclear, for eg: how 0622 is converted to 05:00  1; 0614 to 06:00  2? Thanks and regards,

Comment: more clarification needed, fuzzy logic and unclear question. provide more details, sheets, columns, or your preliminary formulas.

Comment: Also if time is 04:55 it should show count for 05:00  as 1. Basically rounding to the closest time. There are two times for 6am (0622 and 0614) therefore 06:00 -2 count. It should round of to the nearest time and add the number of occurrences also.

Comment: what does this 'count' stand for? your logic is still so fuzzy, put down whatever is presupposed in your mind, we don't know what is going on there in your mind. define everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after struggling to understand what was going on, here is the simple solution:

first let me clarify again:
*column A*: but pasted as **text** originally and in ***hhmm*** format, but you need to reformat them as simple numbers, so you will lose those **0** s at the beginning of certain data.

*column B*: we put down our time ranges, as you said, starting from 12:30 AM, so i put it down as **0030** of which the zeros are not visible anymore in number format. This range starts from **30** and increments by 100, until it stops at *2330* instead of going to 2430. this will be reflected in the formula for the last cell in *column D*.

*column C*: the hour ranges against which we round and count the data in **A**.

*column D*: we put down the following formula in ***D2*** :

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">"&$B2,A:A,"<"&$B3)
```

and drag and fill down until the **last but one** cell. 
for the last cell **D25** we change the **greater/smaller than** signs, and use the following formula (only for this cell):

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<"&$B25,A:A,"<"&$B2)
```

[image]

Try these formulas, if it doesn't work, download the example sheet,
here is the example sheet i created for this purpose, [downloadable from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5wu4057x1g6po9/time_range.count.xlsx?dl=0)

 and if you still have questions, don't hesitate to put them in the commentaries.